# Vue.jsとBootstrapを両方使うのはありですか

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap

フロントエンド開発を勉強しています。BootstrapやVue.jsを両方使うことはありでしょうか？
Bootstrapで見た目を整えて、Vue.jsのトランジションとアニメーションで動きをつけようと思っています
どちらもフロント関係のフレームワークなので両方使っていいのか疑問に思っています

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap は CSS フレームワークですが、アラート、ドロップダウンやモーダルダイアログなど一部のコンポーネントは JavaScript により制御されています。このため、 Vue.js を導入すると Bootstrap と Vue.js の機能が競合し、**正常に動作しない**可能性があります。

そこで、この問題を解決するために [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) を用いることが出来ます。[BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) は Bootstrap の機能を Vue.js のコンポーネントとして統合しているため、前述の問題が解消されています。ただし、現時点では Bootstrap および Vue.js の**最新バージョンに未対応**という点に注意する必要があります。一方で、 Bootstrap の動的な機能を使用しておらず、純粋に CSS のみを使う場合には**直接 Bootstrap を用いる**ことが出来ます。